# how to mention user in android app

Tags: android, instagram, callouts

I want to refer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389150/how-to-mention-users-with-in-app-like-instagram) , on how to implement the mention feature, but for android.

I want to know how it goes in the database specifically .

Comment: Use the open source library by Linkedin if you don't want to dig how it works
https://engineering.linkedin.com/android/open-sourcing-spyglass-flexible-library-implementing-mentions-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the answer was already provided the old post,

> Listen to the input. When the user types an @, followed by a
>   character, make a call to an url on your server
>   (/user/lookup/?username=joe for example) that routes to a view which
>   looks up up users beginning with joe. Return it as json and display it
>   in a dropdown.

To make is much simpler, you need to use `@` as a keyword that is going to be used for understanding the beginning of a user name .

e.g. user types the following message

> ... was with @nour at NYC

in Java you can detect the `@` using regular expression,

```
boolean foundMatch = false;
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:@)\\b");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();
```

This will match if the input string has a `@` keyword

Now once you get the `@` keyword take all character after `@` till you get a white space. In this example `nour` should be the result since its starts after `@` and ends before a `white space`.

In the server part you can the the recognized name as a `USER_NAME`,

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = "nour";
```

Of-course the username needs to the unique.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please can you take a look at this . https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/176-how-to-implment-hashtags-and-callouts-in-android  , can you please tell me what to change to make it from database rather than simple array. shall I have the same classes provided or can I make it simpler

Comment: I ran their project and no this is not the thing I want to do .. :( still lost . any tutorials ?

Comment: I need your help like this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765364/parse-auto-suggestion-query-results-based-on-app-data I wanted to add a comment on his question, but I don't have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 1):

It's mainly done by AutoCompleteTextView and handling the key events. I can't write such a code. I can give you simple main ideas. You listen to the user clicks on the keyboard by overrinding `onKeyUp()` method

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_AT:
        // @ is clicked
        // get the usernames
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

now you should start getting usernames from the database, put them inside the AutoCompleteTextView adapter to be filtered according to the user entries and when the user selects a friend or someone to be mentioned "or many" you add them to an ArrayList and push a notification to them.

Comment: do you have tutorial or anything for this ?

Comment: @AdamahNour No, unfortunately you have to learn that alone

Comment: Use the open source library if you don't want to dig how it works
https://engineering.linkedin.com/android/open-sourcing-spyglass-flexible-library-implementing-mentions-android